# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'

Tags: android, maven, android-library, maven-publish

I'm trying to create a library. On jitpack.io, I see the following error log:

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'mavenLocal'
Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist: '/home/jitpack/build/app/build/outputs/aar/app-release.aar'.

What is the reason for this? How can I solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like there is no artifact created after the build process. Are there more errors in the output? If possible try adding the stacktrace of Jitpack.